# Illustrator CS6: How to stop Action from repeating itself?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, actions

Illustrator CS6.

Action is very simple.

1. User Input: Select an object
2. Call Action

   - Set Document Color Mode to CMYK
   - Set Color for selected object
   - Lock object

[image]

That **should** be the end of it. However, these steps **repeat** themselves a second time.

[image]

You can see the repeat above and the resulting error for the `Lock` step 
(since it's already been run and nothing is then selected).

I *did* have a couple additional action steps - save and close. But due to the repeat those steps wreaked havoc if multiple AI files were open at the same time. Often *crashing* the app entirely. So, I whittled this down to the minimum and thats when I saw the actual issue was due an undesired repeat.

I'm pulling my hair out as to *why* the action repeats itself. I'm trying to do away with the error message for the lock step.

Any ideas why an Action would just decide to repeat itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some troubleshooting...

The "repeat" appears to be due a **shortcut conflict**.

If the Action is run by *clicking the play button* at the bottom of the **Actions Panel**, then the repeat does **not** occur. The action only repeats when using a shortcut, designated in the Action Options:

[image]

To solve this, ensure the shortcut assigned does **not** conflict with any other usage for the *entire operating system*. If the Action's assigned shortcut conflicts, the action seems to repeat.

---

Hunting down the actual conflict can be a quest in itself.

*Most* of the F keys *within Illustrator* are used for the Window menu shortcuts (`Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts > Menus`) ... but the conflict *can* extend across the entire OS, at least here. In most instances the OS shortcut is called first (but may *not* actually run because Illustrator is the foreground application), then Illustrator sees the call. So, you get essentially a double-call when using the shortcut if there is a conflict.

Comment: That is a very good catch.

Comment: I was amazed that Google offered *nothing* regarding this.

Comment: Might this be a mac only bug @Scott

Comment: @joojaa Could be.. but the conflict can also occur with the F keys in AI directly. There's no warning or anything if you set an action's F key to an existing F key shortcut (for window menu items).

Comment: Probably moot since CS6 is so old now.