# Shortcut to "apply italic" randomly breaking on InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I've changed the hotkey for "apply italics" to selected text to F2. For some reason, on some documents, that just stops working, even if I revert the shortcut to the default Shift+Control+I. I use the same fonts, same styles, same everything. Even if I create a new text box with basic paragraph and no character styles, F2 doesn't work. Once it breaks, it does not come back. If I create a new document, it works again (on that new document only).

I also have F1 for bold, which never fails (I press once, bold is applied. I press again, bold is removed) and F3 for sentence case, which also never broke on me. Italics is the only one that constantly breaks, on several different documents, for no apparent reason, after working normally for some time.

It gets weirder. If I manually apply italics to text, then press F2, the program can recognize it and remove the italics. But then if I press F2 again, it won't apply italics no matter what.

Edit: The font I'm using has an italic face and is the shortcut is proven to work with it (on other documents I have). Strangely enough, If I create a new text box and change the font, the shortcut works. So the issue may be font-related somehow.

Any tips on what may be causing this?

Comment: Chances are there's a conflict and F2 *may* be used for another command in InDesign (or even the OS). I know this is an [issue with Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/144290/illustrator-cs6-how-to-stop-action-from-repeating-itself), probably the same with InDesign.

Comment: @Scott That's not the case because the standard Ctrl+Shift+I shortcut also stops working. Also as I mentioned, if I manually apply italics, the shorcut can be used to kind of "apply again" and therefore revert the text back to normal.

Comment: Pretty difficult for other users to provide any answer since this seems to be such a localized issue. I'm assuming you've verified the font in use actually has an italic face. If there is no italic face or it's called oblique, I don't think InDesign creates a faux italic or will use oblique.

Comment: @Scott Yes the font has an italic face, it's Minion Pro. And the shortcut works fine with it on some documents. But now that you mentioned it, I created a new text box and changed the font to Times New Roman to test, and the shortcut worked! So you're in the right track, it may be something font-related. Whatever it is, it's very obscure and not very obvious... For now, I've cloned a document in which the shortcut is working on Minion Pro, to create my new one.

Comment: Minion is *often* the source of font conflicts here... Apple may install it, Adobe Installs another version, etc...

Comment: @Scott interesting, I've never head about that... I noticed some instances of the issue appear after packaging a document and reopening it. Maybe the font compiled is a different version, or something like that. I'll keep that in mind, thanks for your time and advice!